# Move headers as part of detail with shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have an input file that I need to convert to be DB friendly.

Original:

```
H|cust_id|order_no
D|itemcode|itemdesc
D|itemcode|itemdesc
```

Desired output:

```
itemcode|itemdesc|cust_id|order_no
itemcode|itemdesc|cust_id|order_no
```

I'm reading about `sed` but can't understand it.

Comment: That's correct. A file will have a header and dozens of details.

Comment: My question is: Can the input file have _multiple header lines_, each followed by associated detail lines? In other words: is the file made up of _groups_ (blocks) of lines, each composed of a header line followed by detail lines?

Comment: No.A file has just one header and detail. Is like invoice per file. what I would also like to do is to put the first header field into a variable if that's possible with awk.

Comment: Got it. I assume you mean that you want the first header field in a _shell_ variable, right? `awk` can't define _shell_ variables for you, so you'll need an extra command: `firstHeaderField=$(head -1 file | cut -d'|' -f2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a whole heap easier in `awk` than `sed`:

```
awk -F'|' '$1=="H" { c=$2; o=$3 } $1=="D" { printf("%s|%s%|%s|%s\n", $2, $3, c, o) }'
```

If it has to be done in `sed`, then the hold space is the key.  In a file `script.sed`:

```
sed -e '/^H|/{ s/^H|//; h; d; }' \
    -e '/^D|/{ s/^D|//; G; s/\n/|/; }'
```

The first line matches `H` lines, removes the `H|`, and saves what is left in the hold space, and deletes the line to prevent anything being printed.

The second line matches `D` lines, removes the `D|`, appends a newline and the contents of the hold space to the pattern space, replaces the newline with a pipe, and lets the result be printed.

Given input file `data`:

```
H|cust_id-1|order_no-11
D|itemcode-1|itemdesc-1
D|itemcode-2|itemdesc-2
H|cust_id-2|order_no-22
D|itemcode-3|itemdesc-3
D|itemcode-4|itemdesc-4
```

Sample output:

```
$ awk -F '|' '$1 == "H" { c=$2; o=$3 } $1 == "D" { printf("%s|%s%|%s|%s\n", $2, $3, c, o) }' data
itemcode-1|itemdesc-1|cust_id-1|order_no-11
itemcode-2|itemdesc-2|cust_id-1|order_no-11
itemcode-3|itemdesc-3|cust_id-2|order_no-22
itemcode-4|itemdesc-4|cust_id-2|order_no-22
$ sed -e '/^H|/{ s/^H|//; h; d; }' -e '/^D|/{ s/^D|//; G; s/\n/|/; }' data
itemcode-1|itemdesc-1|cust_id-1|order_no-11
itemcode-2|itemdesc-2|cust_id-1|order_no-11
itemcode-3|itemdesc-3|cust_id-2|order_no-22
itemcode-4|itemdesc-4|cust_id-2|order_no-22
$
```

Comment: thanks. that works and awk seems bit more clear but how  this part works ? "$2, $3,$4, c, o, r" is $2,$3 the header field variable?

Comment: @causita: `$2`, for instance, refers to the 2nd field of the _current input line_, based on the field separator specified via `-F` - this is a generic `awk` mechanism. By contrast, it is the `c` and `o` variables - saved in a previous pass matching a _header_ line - that contain the header values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibly easier to understand solution using *two* `sed` commands (assumes input file `file`):

```
# Extract header values from the 1st line, dropping the 1st column.
headerValues=$(sed -E '1 s/[^|]*\|//; q' file)

# Append header values to all subsequent lines, dropping the 1st column.
sed -En '2,$ s/[^|]*\|(.*)/\1|'"$headerValues"'/p' file

# Additional requirement, added later by the OP:
# Store the first header value separately in shell variable $firstHeaderValue.
IFS='|' read -r firstHeaderValue rest <<<"$headerValues"
```

Note:

- Assumes that each file has only *one* header line, which must be the first line, followed by detail lines.
- Makes no assumptions about the width or number of columns.
- The `sed` commands should work on both Linux and OSX/FreeBSD.